# PyTorch emotion model labels normalization approach

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, dataset

Im trying to build ML emotion model in PyTorch.

I have emotion labels taken from CMU-MOSEI dataset in data frame as below:

| happy | sad | anger | surprise | disgust | fear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.33 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 2.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.33 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.33 | 0.33 | 2.0 | 0.0 |

Each emotion can be in range between `0.0 -> 3.0`

Question is:

#### How to perform normalization to range `0 -> 1` on this data:

##### 1. Normalize each column by:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

for emo in ['happy', 'sad', 'anger', 'surprise', 'disgust', 'fear']:
    mosei[emo] = minmax_scale(mosei[emo])
```

which give me ie:

`1.33,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0` -> `0.44,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0`

`2.0,0.0,0.0,0.33,0.0,0.0` -> `0.67,0.0,0.0,0.11,0.0,0.0`

`0.0,0.0,1.33,0.33,2.0,0.0` -> `0.0,0.0,0.44,0.11,0.67,0.0`

but for last example `sum() > 1`

##### 2. Normalize each column and in data loader perform `softmax()`

```
>>> F.softmax(torch.tensor([0.44,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]), dim=0)
tensor([0.2370, 0.1526, 0.1526, 0.1526, 0.1526, 0.1526])


>>> F.softmax(torch.tensor([0.0,0.0,0.44,0.11,0.67,0.0]), dim=0)
tensor([0.1312, 0.1312, 0.2037, 0.1464, 0.2564, 0.1312])
```

##### 3. Perform normalization by each row instead of columns

```
>>> minmax_scale([1.33,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])


>>> minmax_scale([0.0,0.0,1.33,0.33,2.0,0.0])
array([0.   , 0.   , 0.665, 0.165, 1.   , 0.   ])
```

but again last example `sum() > 1`

- maybe softmax again?

```
F.softmax(torch.tensor([0.   , 0.   , 0.665, 0.165, 1.   , 0.   ]), dim=0)
tensor([0.1131, 0.1131, 0.2199, 0.1334, 0.3074, 0.1131])
```

or maybe there could be different/better normalization approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Softmax is commonly used for normalization in ML.
However, you could also do the following given your df:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'happy': [1.33, 2.0, 0.0],
    'sad': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'anger': [0.0, 0.0, 1.33],
    'surprise': [0.0, 0.33, 0.33],
    'disgust': [0.0, 0.0, 2.0],
    'fear': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_df = df.copy()
for i in df.index:
    normalized_row = df.iloc[i] / df.iloc[i].sum()
    new_df.iloc[i] = normalized_row
```

Where the rows are normalized and sum up to 1.